# Make a title clickable into the post itself. (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'needs',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'category_name' => 'volunteers', //name of category by slug
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => '5')); // how many posts to show

  // Put into the loop
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   $the_query->the_post();
   echo '<tr><td>' . get_the_date() . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';

  endwhile;



  // Restore original Post Data if needed
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'm using this code to correctly display the title and date of a need under the category of volunteer.
I need the title to link to the post itself though and I can't get permalink to work with this code.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If get_the_title() is working for you, there's really no reason why this wouldn't work:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'needs',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'category_name' => 'volunteers', //name of category by slug
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => '5')); // how many posts to show

  // Put into the loop
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   $the_query->the_post();
   echo '<tr><td>' . get_the_date() . '</td>';
   echo '<td><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';

  endwhile;



  // Restore original Post Data if needed
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

try it out!

Comment: This is correct. The other method that also works is this:

    echo '<td><a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' .      get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';

What is the difference between yours and this one? They both work.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

There is no difference, as get_the_ID() is simply a function that gets the ID from the $post variable. 

$post->ID is the more proper and direct way to get that same ID, and you will probably see it more often.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo '<td>' . get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';
```

to

```
echo '<td><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: This method actually linked to the page I was currently on, no to the post itself.